# Debugging a WCF service hosted inside a windows service from an ASP.NET MVC client hosted on local IIS

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-debugging

Friends,
     I have a WCF service that i am trying to  step into locally from my MVC 2 web client .THe WCF service is hosted inside a windows service inside the same solution .I installed the windows service and made sure that it is running.But when i try to step into the WCF service , i get the following error message
  "Cannot step into the remote procedure".

Here is my client and host configurations

Host

```
<host>
    <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior">
        <host>
            <baseAddresses>
                <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/MyService" />
                <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyService" />
            </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="bigTcpArrayBinding" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="" bindingConfiguration="bigArrayBinding" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="IMyServices" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
</host>
```

and 
client is

```
<client>
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:9002/MyService" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="bigTcpArrayBinding" contract="LPS.HAMP.MARS.IHampServices" name="SANDBOX_HampServicesSvcContract" />
</client>
```

I use VS 2010 on windows 7. Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks
RJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can debug a running windows service, go to Debug -> Attach to process -> find the name of the service and VS will attach to this running service.

Comment: Thanks man. I was debugging my web client by attaching that to the w3wp.exe iis process. So can we attch the debugger to more than one process in VS ?

Comment: Yes, I have attached to a few windows services at once, there might be a limit on how many can be attached at once though.